# Query gives me a syntax error in From clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server

This SQL query runs perfectly in an older MS Access file but after recreating it for a newer table it gives me a Syntax error in the from clause.

```
select * from ( with dso as (select month, product_line, third_cust_indic as sales_type,  
                    sum(sales) + sum(beg_snb_ra) as beg_sales,
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `|| ' ' ||` isn't valid syntax either. T-SQL uses plus (`+`) for concatenation, not double pipe (`||`).

Comment: "Query gives me syntax error.." will not help us help you. Where's the error?  It's like you are saying to your mechanic "My car is broken", without any other information.

Comment: So you've just updated your question to say "MS Access" but you have tagged SQL Server? Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

If this is SQL Server, then the `with` statement needs to precede the `select`:

```
with dso as (
      select . . .
      . . .
     )
select . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with dso as (select year, month, product_line_id, third_party_cust_indic as sales_type,  
                    sum(beg_snb_sales) + sum(beg_snb_ra) as beg_snb_sales,  
                    sum(snb_sales) + sum(snb_ra) as snb_sales,  
                    sum(beg_snb_cost) as beg_snb_cost,
                    sum(snb_cost) as snb_cost,
                    sum(spa) as spa_amount, 
                    sum(invoiced_sales) + coalesce(sum(ic_extended_price),0) as invoiced_sales,
                    sum(gross_invoiced_sales) as gross_invoiced_sales, 
                    sum(invoiced_cost)+ coalesce(sum(ic_extended_cost),0) as cost,
                    sum(beg_bl_future) + sum(beg_bl_dated) + sum(beg_bl_alloc) + sum(beg_bl_not_produced) as beginning_backlog,
                    sum(bl_future) + sum(bl_dated) + sum(bl_alloc) + sum(bl_not_produced) as current_backlog, 
                    sum(bl_alloc) as bl_alloc,
                    sum(bl_dated) as bl_dated,
                    sum(bl_future) as bl_future,
                    sum(bl_not_produced) as bl_not_produced,
                    sum(promos) + sum(edi_disc_allowance) + sum(new_store_allowance) + sum(ord_level_disc_allowance) + sum     (rdc_allowance) + sum(cert_rec_allowance) 
                    + sum(defective_allowance) + sum(freight_allowance)  + sum(adv_coop_allowance) + sum(store_svc_allowance) + sum(promo_amt) + sum(below_min_order_fee) as order_level_discounts,
manufacturing_location, inv_legal_entity || ' ' || inv_legal_entity_desc as shipping_location


       from prodsales.monthly_sales_orders
      where year = 2018
        and month = 10
        and (CUST_LEGAL_ENTITY = '001' )
     --  or ar_legal_entity = '001') 
        and PRODUCT_LINE_ID <> '000'
        and BUSINESS_UNIT_ID Not in ('OI','IC','BI','RF')  
      group by year, month, product_line_id, third_party_cust_indic, manufacturing_location, inv_legal_entity || ' ' || inv_legal_entity_desc
     )
, Pl as (select distinct product_line_id as pl from dso)
, YN as (select distinct sales_type as slstyp, year, month, day  from dso)
, pl_indic as (select * from pl, yn)
select * from DSO
```

... though you don't seem to be using PL, YN or PL_INDIC.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like:

```
select * 
from ( 
    with dso as (
        select 
            ...
        from prodsales.monthly_sales_orders
        where
            ...
        )
    and ...
    group by ...
),
Pl as (select ... from dso),
YN as (select ... from dso),
pl_indic as (select ... from YN)
```

There are *a lot* of problems here:

- as answer by Gordon Linoff, the `with` statement must precede the `select`
- the conditions after the end of the declaration of `dso` statement make not sense, they basically cannot relate to anything
- `P1` and `YN` are outside of the `with` statement, whereas their syntax suggest that they should belong to it : `Pl as (...)`)

That's far too many issues to make it possible to provide suggestions on how to rewrite the query. It also makes it extremely unlikely that this ever ran on any database. You would need to entirely revise the logic of this query.